# Crating XLS file from binary data in node.js

Tags: node.js, xls

I received the binary data as response from http request.

In C# I convert the data to byteArray and writhing the byteArray into file creates a readable xls file.

**C# Code:**

```
 HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = _httpClient.GetAsync(endPoint).Result;
 var httpResponseByteArray = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
 File.WriteAllBytes("plateList.xls", httpResponseByteArray);
```

I am looking for a way to implement the same thing in node js.

I`ve tried these methods so far but each created a non-readable file:

```
 const Excel = require('exceljs');
```

**First try - node.js**

```
 var dataBinary = response.data;
 var workbook = new Excel.Workbook(dataBinary);
 await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("Test.xls")
         .then(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', "Create excel file successfully");
          });
```

**Secound try - node.js**

```
 var bufferData = Buffer.from(response.data);
 var workbook = new Excel.Workbook(dataBinary);
 await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("Test.xls")
         .then(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', "Create excel file successfully");
          });
```

Other library:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
```

**Third try - node.js**

```
 fs.writeFileSync("Test.xls", response.data);
```

**Fourth try - node.js**

```
 fs.writeFileSync("Test.xls",  Buffer.from(response.data));
```

And more but nothing work to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// response.data as a arrayBuffer
var data = response.data;
var arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i)
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
var bstr = arr.join("");

/* Call XLSX */
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
    type: "binary"
});

/* Create the file*/
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "carNumbersAllowedFromLPRCamera.xls");

/* Get the work sheet name */
var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];

/* Get worksheet */
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

/* Convert it to json*/
let xlsData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
    raw: true
})
```

Comment: Hi @Naor Levi , how to  made to file excel base64 post?